# Openshift database gear quota exceeded

Tags: python, django, postgresql, openshift

I have a Django app running on OpenShift gear with web balancer enabled. That means I have python app on one gear with 1GB capacity and postgresql database on different gear with 1GB capacity.
Problem is I did not delete log entries in my database and it grew up to 1GB. Now my website is not accessible. I tried to log in to database gear and delete unnecessary entries, but I can not log in because of disk quota exceeded.

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "56ee-lucas03.rhcloud.com" (172.16.3.217) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 36081?
```

How do I log in and delete unnecessary entries? Do I need to buy 1GB extra space and delete those entries? Or is there an easier solution how to log in to database with exceeded disk quota?

---

**EDIT1**:
I tried `rhc app-tidy appname`, returned `Warning: Gear 56ee is using 98.6% of disk quota`. However I still can not login to psql with same error.

```
$ rhc app-start appname
Warning: Gear 56ee is using 98.6% of disk quota
Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/56ee/postgresql
```

Comment: Have you tried to run the tidy command on rhc?

Comment: @JoãoGonçalves hi, EDIT1 added to Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added credit card == upgraded to bronze plan. Added 1GB to database gear, deleted session data and all is well. However, I would be glad if there was an easier way to be able to manage gear even if disk quota was exceeded.